# InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery

Yesterday, my local server HDD crashes and goes for automatic scandisk at start up. I was not in office so I really don't know what had happen. But today when we start Server we are getting

```
130523 10:49:36  InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
```

I try to run scandisk on C: and it found 4 corrupted records, but no bad sector or something. Database Server has around 300 Database, I Am not sure how to recover it. Someone suggest delete Log files and try to set

```
innodb_Force_recovery = 4
```

I try that too, but some of database are unavailable and crash MySql when I try to use them. I am not sure as reloading 300 database is not an easy job.

Edit:

I am on Windows 2008 Web Edition if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're on Windows: the ENFILE error basically says you have too many open files. Not quite sure how exactly you get around it: [in general it is somewhere between 512 and 2048 in a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3b887c.aspx).

Would suggest maybe moving all the files out of the MySQL data directory and trying to recover them one by one.

Comment: Yes I am on Windows 2008, I just reboot Server, and server is working like this from last couple of years. It never had any problem, but due to excessive heat [as it seems] it's HDD crashes yesterday and that is it. So it might be corrupted file system or CRC as I understand that is causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but the error is pointing to another file :

> InnoDB: File name .\ib_logfile0

Deleting (or renaming) both logfiles from the data directory (.\ib_logfile0 and .\ib_logfile1) solves the issue for me.

Comment: Well, there is no question here. This is an answer to the initial question.

Comment: Thanks. this solved my issue, not sure why it happened so sudden