# Mysql cannot start : InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

Mysql doesn't want to startup anymore. Here is the error log, any ideas why ?

```
151102 18:11:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151102 18:11:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151102 18:11:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151102 18:11:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151102 18:11:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151102 18:11:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151102 18:11:18 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151102 18:11:24  InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706568/innodb-operating-system-error-number-23-in-a-file-operation)

Comment: This question is rather for DBAs or sysadmins, than for developers. You may get better answer on such forums.

Comment: @Shadow I know, but that post does not help.

Comment: Probably because you are asking the question from the wrong audience. Besides, if it's truly an OS related problem, then without OS logs it's difficult to tell what the problem might be.