# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

My wamp server just stopped working and after troubleshooting i realized that its the Mysql Server and so i checked the error log which is below.

```
160606 12:23:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160606 12:23:14  InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File operation call: 'read'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
160606 12:33:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160606 12:33:17  InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File operation call: 'read'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Comment: This one is already answered. First hit with google on InnoDB Error 23: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706568/innodb-operating-system-error-number-23-in-a-file-operation. Please do some research next time.

Comment: You have a corrupted database or a bad disk. Restore your last backup